# React js add Class onFocus and remove Class onBlur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Below I attached my code When i focus on input add class both input and when blur removed class in both input but i want to add class each input when specific input focus and blur. I use focus state to add and remove class in when input focus and blur.

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    focus: false
  };

  onFocus = () => {
    this.setState({focus: true})
  };
  onBlur = () => {
    this.setState({focus: false})
  };

  render() {
    const { focus } = this.state;
    return (
      <Form>
        <img src={`/images/login/profile1.svg`} alt="Profile" />
        <h2 className="title">Login</h2>

        <div className={`input-div one`} >
          <div className="i">
            <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
          </div>
          <div className="div">
            <Form.Field>
              <input
                  className={`input ${focus ? "hello" : ""} `}
                  placeholder="Email"
                  onBlur={this.onBlur} 
                  onFocus={this.onFocus.bind(this)}
                  type="email"
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
              />
            </Form.Field>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={`input-div pass`}>
          <div className="i">
            <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
          </div>
          <div className="div">
            <Form.Field>
              <input
                  className={`input ${focus ? "hello" : ""} `}
                  placeholder="password"
                  onBlur={this.onBlur} 
                  onFocus={this.onFocus.bind(this)}
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
              />
            </Form.Field>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Button className="fire-login-btn">Login</Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event object you get in `onFocus` and `onBlur` handler to add or remove classes to the dom element.

Here I created an example showing it for you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-oskar-hr9lb?file=/src/App.js

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If i want to add class outside of input tag what could i do ?

Comment: For that you can use refs, create a ref and assign it to a component then `ref.current` will point to that dom element. You can do what you want with that ref when input is focused or blurred